# Can't execute a javascript function from page served by Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a Node.js application that is rendering a pug file to display. Within the pug file, I am trying to use typeahead.js to autocomplete a search string. The external javascript library (i.e., typeahead) appears to load fine, but is not getting called upon input to the search bar.

I'm probably missing something related to Node here. Any pointers that could help? Here's the sample code that is pulling queries from a movie database. Execution is node ./bin/www

views/index.pug

```
doctype html
html
   head
    script(src='../javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')
    script(src='../javascripts/typeahead.bundle.min.js')
    script(src='../javascripts/danielta.js')
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
block content
    h1="Search"
        input(class="typeahead")
```

public/javascripts/danielta.js

```
   // Instantiate the Bloodhound suggestion engine
    var movies = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: function(datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
      },
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      remote: {
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%QUERY&api_key=f22e6ce68f5e5002e71c20bcba477e7d',
        transform: function(response) {
          // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript object array
          return $.map(response.results, function(movie) {
            return {
              value: movie.original_title
            };
          });
        }
      }
    });

    movies.initialize();

    // Instantiate the Typeahead UI
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
      display: 'value',
      source: movies
    });
```

public/stylesheets/style.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"Prociono";
    src: url("../font/Prociono-Regular-webfont.ttf");
}
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 750px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu, .gist {
    text-align: left;
}
html {
    color: #333333;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.title, .example-name {
    font-family: Prociono;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.title {
    font-size: 64px;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}
.example {
    padding: 30px 0;
}
.example-name {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.demo {
    margin: 50px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.typeahead, .tt-query, .tt-hint {
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    width: 396px;
}
.typeahead {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.typeahead:focus {
    border: 2px solid #0097CF;
}
.tt-query {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
.tt-hint {
    color: #999999;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    width: 422px;
}
.tt-suggestion {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 3px 20px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
    background-color: #0097CF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
    margin: 0;
}
.gist {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.example-twitter-oss .tt-suggestion {
    padding: 8px 20px;
}
.example-twitter-oss .tt-suggestion + .tt-suggestion {
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.example-twitter-oss .repo-language {
    float: right;
    font-style: italic;
}
.example-twitter-oss .repo-name {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.example-twitter-oss .repo-description {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.example-sports .league-name {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin: 0 20px 5px;
    padding: 3px 0;
}
.example-arabic .tt-dropdown-menu {
    text-align: right;
}
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

bin/www

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('myapp:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: There's simply no way we can help you without seeing the relevant code pasted into your answer.  Questions here about code MUST include the relevant code.  I can't even tell from your question if the problem is in the Javascript in your web page or if it's in the autocomplete logic on your node.js server.  And, once you know which of those it is, we will have to see the relevant code to offer a solution.

Comment: Also, please fix the title of your question to be something a lot more specific to your question.  All of node.js programming uses Javascript functions just fine.

Comment: Do you understand that Javascript in your web page can only communicate with your node.js server via an Ajax call or a webSocket connection.  You can't call code in your node.js server directly from your web page.  node.js runs on your server.  Code in your web page runs inside the browser.  They are on different computers in different parts of the internet.

Comment: Apologies. I've added code to the question and modified the title. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it is not a race condition?
What if you use $(document).ready?

```
   $(function() {
       // Instantiate the Typeahead UI
       $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
          display: 'value',
          source: movies
       });
   });
```

Comment: That did it! Unclear why that works though. Can you explain?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, well your javascript code was being executed before the html page was rendered. So when your jquery selector $('.typeahead') ran the html markup was not there to be found, there was nothing with the class typeahead to bind to. Using the jquery dom ready wrapper ensures that the page/html is fully loaded before running the js code.